# Horizontal scrolling on windows phone 7 textblock

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, textblock, horizontal-scrolling

How does one set a TextBlock on windows phone to be horizontally scrollable. I know you can set it to wrap-text but I don't want this. If the given text falls outside the boundries of the TextBlock I want the user to be able to scroll horizontally.

I can't seem to find an attribute in the XAML that allows one to do this. Like I said, all I'm finding is to have the text wrap, which I don't want.

Code:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding COM}" Foreground="Black" 
           FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer` in order to achieve this effect:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
      <TextBlock Text="this is really long text that will probably go off the screen any second now"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The text will all be on one line. If you want the text to be on multiple lines, set `TextWrapping` to `Wrap`, and specify a Width for the `TextBlock`.

I recommend at least putting a width of 2048, as that is the maximum dimension for any Windows Phone control ([How to increase height limit of the TextBlock control in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696050/how-to-increase-height-limit-of-the-textblock-control-in-windows-phone)).